# MySQL add time to time stamp

Tags: php

I'm trying to run a query where a check is done if a time is in between a time and that time + 90 mins.
I have 1 time value being passed in. So lets say the time being passed in is 1pm. I'd like to check if a time is between 1pm and 2.30pm.

I have tried passing in a second param adding the seconds with `strtotime()` and I have the below

```
AND r.start_time BETWEEN '19:00:00.0000' AND '19:00:00.0000', INTERVAL + 90 MINUTE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use strtotime(...)+5400 to express 90 minutes.
For example:

```
$times = strtotime('19:00:00.0000');
$end_time = $times + 5400;
$query = "SELECT ... WHERE r.start_time BETWEEN '$times' AND '$end_times'";
```